# How to make input (checkboxes) and label line up?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input, label

We have the following structure below for the html and it is resulting in the checkboxes showing in the same row.

How can we get each checkbox and label to show in just one row using a CSS solution?

Code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value1</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value2</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value3</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value4</label>
</div>
```

Goal/objective:

1. Without having to use extra HTML tags such as `<div>`, make every checkbox and label show up in one row
2. a pure css solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.list {
 display: table-row 
}
```

You can use .list to target the class of your div

```css
.list {
display: table-row
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value1</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value2</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value3</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see how this changes things in the output.

Comment: @MrLister I think his solution was showing a row in the snippet but not the actual solution. The css provided, ensures it will display in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```css
label {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">

  <label><input type="checkbox"> value1</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox"> value2</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox"> value3</label>

  <label><input type="checkbox"> value4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the HTML, you have the option of inserting a line feed after each label using CSS.

```css
.list label::after {
   white-space:pre; content:'\0A';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value1</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value2</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value3</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label> value4</label>
</div>
```